# Combine frame: Generic Parsing No value associated with key CodingKeys using

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am trying to parse below josn, but not able to parse (using Combine for service API).

```
{
  "data": {
    "user_data": {
      "u_id": 14252,
      "first_name": "Amar",
      "last_name": "",
      "email": "sample@gmail.com",
      "birth_date": "",
      "status": 1,
      "SubscriptionPlanId": null,
      "subscriptionexpireddate": "2021-11-09T10:40:02.000Z",
      "stripe_customer_id": "",
      "stripe_customer_token": "",
      "image": "dfdfcf7.jpg",
      "password": "anypassword",
      "country": "",
      "gender": "",
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKVI1NiJ9.eyJpc3N1ZWQiOiIyMDIxLTEyLTAyVDEwOjE0OjA1Wjk3In0.MznqecyVK6sozp6Fo3em8Ze_ZqSuE3YR2j_oCb1HsZc",
      "dance_org": "",
      "create_time": "2022-02-10T16:14:56.000Z",
      "facebook_id": "",
      "google_id": "11600922982196",
      "twitter_id": "",
      "apple_id": "",
      "inapp_product_id": "com.amar.purchase.key",
      "device": "ios",
      "receipt_data": null,
      "original_transaction_id": "",
      "promo_applied": null,
      "notes": null,
      "wallet": 0,
      "referral": "Ms2dJEqU",
      "group_name": null,
      "version": "iOS 3.1.6 (5)"
    }
  },
  "success": true,
  "current_time": "2021-12-02T10:14:05.953Z",
  "error": 1000
}
```

**Getting below Error**

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "user_data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"user_data\", intValue: nil) (\"user_data\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

For testing purpose, I comment data and create_time then working fine, but I comment only data then also getting error for current_time.

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "current_time", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"current_time\", intValue: nil) (\"current_time\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is my Response model

```
public struct UserLoginResponse: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success, error, data
        case currentTime = "current_time"
    }

    let success: Bool
    let currentTime: String? //": "2021-11-20T13:00:54.654Z",
    let error: Int
    let data: LoggedInUserData

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        data = try container.decode(LoggedInUserData.self, forKey: .data)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        currentTime = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .currentTime)
        error = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .error)
    }
}

public struct LoggedInUserData: Decodable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userData = "user_data"
    }
    
    let userData: LoginedInUserInfo
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        userData = try container.decode(LoginedInUserInfo.self, forKey: .userData)
    }
}

public struct LoginedInUserInfo: Decodable {
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "u_id"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case email //= "email"
        case birthDate = "birth_date"
        case status //= "status"
        case subscriptionPlanId = "SubscriptionPlanId"
        case subscriptionexpireddate //= "subscriptionexpireddate"
        case stripeCustomerId = "stripe_customer_id"
        case stripeCustomerToken = "stripe_customer_token"
        case image //= "image"
        case password //= "password"
        case country //= "country"
        case gender //= "gender"
        case token //= "token"
        case danceOrg = "dance_org"
        case createTime = "create_time"
        case facebookId = "facebook_id"
        case googleId = "google_id"
        case twitterId = "twitter_id"
        case appleId = "apple_id"
        case inappProductId = "inapp_product_id"
        case device //= "device"
        case receiptData = "receipt_data"
        case originalTransactionId = "original_transaction_id"
        case promoApplied = "promo_applied"
        case notes //= "notes"
        case wallet //= "wallet"
        case referral //= "referral"
        case groupName = "group_name"
        case version //= "version"
    }

    let userID: Int
    var firstName: String
    let lastName: String?
    let email: String?
    let birthDate: String?
    let status: Int
    let subscriptionPlanId: String?
    let subscriptionexpireddate: String?
    let stripeCustomerId: String?
    let stripeCustomerToken: String?
    let image: String?
    let password: String
    let country: String?
    let gender: String?
    let token: String?
    let danceOrg: String?
    let createTime: String?
    let facebookId: String?
    let googleId: String?
    let twitterId: String?
    let appleId: String?
    let inappProductId: String
    let device: String?
    let receiptData: String?
    let originalTransactionId: String?
    let promoApplied: String?
    let notes: String?
    var wallet: Int
    let referral: String?
    let groupName: String?
    let version: String?
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        userID = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .userID)
        firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        birthDate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .birthDate)
        status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        subscriptionPlanId = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subscriptionPlanId)
        subscriptionexpireddate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subscriptionexpireddate)
        stripeCustomerId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .stripeCustomerId)
        stripeCustomerToken = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .stripeCustomerToken)
        image = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .image)
        password = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .password)
        country = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)
        gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
        token = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
        danceOrg = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .danceOrg)
        createTime = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .createTime)
        facebookId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .facebookId)
        googleId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .googleId)
        twitterId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .twitterId)
        appleId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .appleId)
        inappProductId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .inappProductId)
        device = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .device)
        receiptData = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .receiptData)
        originalTransactionId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .originalTransactionId)
        promoApplied = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .promoApplied)
        notes = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .notes)
        wallet = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .wallet)
        referral = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .referral)
        groupName = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .groupName)
        version = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .version)
        }
}
```

Here is my service manager API body

```
static func fetch<T: Decodable>(with request: URLRequest, session: URLSessionType) -> AnyPublisher<T, MusicNetworkError>  {
        return  session.sessionWithConfig().dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
              .tryMap { (data: Data, response: URLResponse) in //tryMap validate provide feature to validate first, if ok then return data oterwise error. while Map does not provide any validation
                  guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                      throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                  }
                  return data
              }
              .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) //
              .mapError({ error in
                switch error {
                case is Swift.DecodingError:
                    print("Error while fetch = \(error)") **//failing always**
                  return .decodingFailed
                case let urlError as URLError:
                  return .sessionFailed(error: urlError)
                default:
                  return .other(error)
                }
              })
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Please suggest, where I am doing wrong.

I tried with HARD coded string, same Decodable class working fine.

```
static func testFunction()  {
            
        let jsonData = """
        {
          "data": {
            "user_data": {
              "u_id": 14252,
              "first_name": "Amar",
              "last_name": "",
              "email": "a@gmail.com",
              "birth_date": "",
              "status": 1,
              "SubscriptionPlanId": null,
              "subscriptionexpireddate": "2021-11-09T10:40:02.000Z",
              "stripe_customer_id": "",
              "stripe_customer_token": "",
              "image": "3dd3b-a95522a0fcf7.jpg",
              "password": "mypass",
              "country": "",
              "gender": "",
              "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKVdR_lEw",
              "dance_org": "",
              "create_time": "2022-02-10T16:14:56.000Z",
              "facebook_id": "",
              "google_id": "1d2196dd",
              "twitter_id": "",
              "apple_id": "",
              "inapp_product_id": "com.my.company",
              "device": "ios",
              "receipt_data": null,
              "original_transaction_id": "",
              "promo_applied": null,
              "notes": null,
              "wallet": 0,
              "referral": "Ms2dJEqU",
              "group_name": null,
              "version": "iOS 30.6 (5)"
            }
          },
          "success": true,
          "current_time": "2021-11-20T13:00:54.654Z",
          "error": 1000
        }
""".data(using: .utf8)!
            
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
          let user = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
        print("User is = \(user)") **//This is working fine with same UserLoginResponse**
```

but not working with below line

```
.decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

Comment: When I try to decode with your struct's I get a different error message and when looking close the error message you posted looks incomplete.

Comment: Basically it looks like you have an issue with optional properties, you need to use `encodeIfPresent(...)` instead of `encode(...)` for them. Or remove all of your `init(from decoder:)` completely, I don't see how they are needed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried after removing init from decoder, still same error.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If tried without data key, just for success, error and createTime .... it is failing with keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "current_time", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"current_time\", intValue: nil) (\"current_time\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Once I tested with HARD code string, below link working fine same Decodable class 
let user = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)

But same decodable class not working for 
.decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

Comment: @user7167475 If you can decode a hard-coded string but not the API version, wouldn't you think it is an issue with the API's JSON? What different JSON does it give you for different results

Comment: I agree, maybe skip the decoding of the result and map data to string and print the results

Comment: JoakimDanielson George, Thank you. I changed few things and working fine. Decode all parameter with try?, added headers like Content type as "application/json" in http body.